# CAD Solidworks assembly to Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, cad, solidworks

I`m trying to find a way to import SW assembly (robot cell) into Unity3D, I came across different non-open sources on the internet such as CAD-link, Cad exchanger, etc.
The only idea that I have on this problem is to save every single part/model from the assembly as an obj/gltf file and reassemble it in Unity again, is there any other way to do so, for example, to save objects as JSON files or something like that?

Until now I tried to save my assembly as a gltf/glb file, but that does not help me on this problem since I need my model to be fully operated (constrained, maited) as it is in SolidWorks.

Answer (score 0):

Unity uses FBX so you need to find a way to convert to that from Solidworks. I believe Solidworks Visualize has this capability. Another way would to be save your Solidworks files in a neutral format such as STEP/IGES/STL and then use different software to convert to FBX - Rhino or Blender should work.